# DMS unable to write to S3 bucket after upgrading to 3.4.7

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-dms

After upgrading a DMS instance from 3.4.6 -> 3.4.7, the replication task is no longer able to write to S3 for the intermediary step before sending the data to a redshift cluster, the task is a Mysql -> Redshift full load + cdc task.

The errors are ones like this

```
2023-09-05T09:25:03 [SOURCE_UNLOAD   ]E:  AccessDenied: Access Denied [1001705]  (transfer_client.cpp:510)
2023-09-05T09:25:03 [SOURCE_UNLOAD   ]E:  Failed to upload file '/rdsdbdata/data/tasks/CYN4WXD7XM63C6J6UOV5WX2ZW5KBB5JC5LDQRLA/cloud/bulkload/4/LOAD00000001.csv' to bucket 'xxx-bucket-name-xxx' as 'ingestion/CYN4WXD7XM63C6J6UOV5WX2ZW5KBB5JC5LDQRLA/4/LOAD00000001.csv', status = 4 (FAILED) [1001705]  (transfer_client.cpp:514)
```

The IAM role dms-access-for-endpoint role grants s3:* access to xxx-bucket-name-xxx and xxx-bucket-name-xxx/*

All connection tests for endpoints pass successfully.

I have confirmed that the vpc endpoint to S3 is working correctly, by spinning up an ec2 instance in the same subnet/SG that the dms instance is in, and running a traceroute to s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com which shows only one hop.

I am able to manually COPY data from s3 bucket into redshift so i don't think this is redshift related

Does anyone have any idea what else might be the issue here

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be that DMS is unable to write to a custom provided bucket for the redshift endpoint after the version upgrade, if the settings are changed to let DMS create a bucket itself, it works fine for some reason